# sumtable() in R gives irreproducible error

Tags: r

I recently started using the sumtable() as part of the vtable package in R. However, I keep getting an error when I run code on my machine that doesn't reproduce on my colleague's machine. The problem seems to come from the factor.numeric=TRUE option. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (If this would be better at cross-validated, please let me know)

First, this only happens with some datasets. The code works fine on the mtcars dataset; no errors at all.

```
###Attempt 1
names <- c('cyl', 'vs', 'am', 'gear', 'carb')
mtcars[,names] <- lapply(mtcars[,names] , factor) 
mtcars2<-mtcars
mtcars2$cyl<-factor(mtcars2$cyl)
sumtable(mtcars2, c('mpg','cyl','disp'), factor.numeric = TRUE)
```

That code works perfectly. However, when I download the World Values Survey in .csv format it doesn't work at all. The dataset is free to download here: https://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSDocumentationWV5.jsp.

```
###Attempt 2
WVS <- read_delim("[my path]/WV5_Data_csv_v20180912.csv", delim = ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
WVS <- replace(WVS, WVS < 0, NA)
WVS2<-WVS %>% select('V147', 'V91','V95','V123','V235','V255')
WVS2$V255<-factor(WVS2$V255)
sumtable(WVS2 %>% select(V255, V95), factor.numeric = TRUE)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'va'
```

However, note that:

```
###Attempt 3
sumtable(WVS2 %>% select(V255, V95))
```

Works perfectly.

I sent this to a colleague to see if he could see what was wrong with it. Using the exact same file and copy-pasted code, he did not get the error message.

I have no idea why this could be happening. I have uninstalled and reinstalled all my packages. I have uninstalled and reinstalled R (and RStudio). Could there be something about how I read the file into R? I downloaded the same file in .dta format and read it in using read_dta() and I got the same error message.

Thanks for any help you can provide on this in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this appears to be something odd (a change?) in the way that tibbles respond to a certain variable-selection syntax. For now the problem can be resolved by using as.data.frame(WVS2), but I will fix this.